# 'undefined reference' with 'not declared'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker

this is a simple problem in c compiling and linking. But I want to discuss the principle of compiler and linker.

```
void f();
int main()
{
    f();
}
```

this code receive error message "undefined reference to 'f()'"

```
int main()
{
    f();
}
```

this code receive error message "f was not declared in this scope"
what is the difference?
and what 's more,  the code

```
void f()
{

}
int main()
{
    f();
}
```

runs well.

Comment: In the second example, `f` is neither declared nor defined. In the first, it's declared but not defined. In the last, it's both declared and defined.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between "declared" and "defined".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you declare a function, but don't define it.  It compiles properly, but doesn't link because there is no definition for `f`.  Hence the linker error.

In the second case, you attempt to call an undeclared symbol.  The compiler doesn't know what `f` is, so it issues an error.  It's a different problem from a different stage of the compilation process, so the message is different.

In the third case, you have a well-defined program (except that `main` fails to return a value).  `f` is both declared and defined.  The program should compile, link, and execute properly.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify this question. You should know how the code becomes a executable program.
The first step is "Compile". Compile your source code into *.o file which is binary file.
The second if "Link". Combine your *.o file into executable file.
In your first example, you declare the function `f` ,but you don't define it. So when the Linker links the *.o file, it can't find function `f`.
In your second example, you use function `f` without declaration or implementation. So the Compiler report an error.
In your third example, the function `f` implementation is ahead using it. It's right.